# ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: java, mysql, angular, database

I am working with a database which is working fine but I get an error when I want to display my information in a table.

I am getting the following error:

```
 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6202:31
    at XMLHttpRequest.proto.<computed> [as open] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4663:24)
```

My service class:

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

     import {Certificaten} from "../certificaten";
     import {Observable} from "rxjs";
     import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";

     @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
      })
     export class CertificatenService {

     private certificatenUrl: string;

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

     public findAll(): Observable<Certificaten[]> {
     return this.http.get<Certificaten[]>(`${environment.CVUrl}certificaten`);
     }
     public save(certificaten: Certificaten) {
     return this.http.post<Certificaten>(this.certificatenUrl, Certificaten);
      }

       }
```

Kindly guide for this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need anything more....

Just you need to add couple of lines code.

Open **app.moudule.ts** file

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
  HttpClientModule
]
```

That's it it will working fine.

Comment: fortunately for me i already imported it. unfortunatly this did not solve my problem. thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

can you check the value of your `environment.CVUrl`? I think you missed the `http://` or `https://` if you put any ip like '192.168....' then you have to use 
environment.CVUrl = 'http://192.168....' hope this will help you